# Select multiple columns with an interval in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with following columns:

`A` , `B` , `C` , `D` , `E` , `F` , `G` , `H`

I want to select all the columns with a specific interval, say *n*.For example if *n=2* and I start from `A`, I would select :

`A`,`B`,`E`,`F` (select the first two,drop the next two and so on)

If I start from the end, I would select:

`H`,`G`,`D`,`C`

I can even start from any random column in between.What would be an efficient way of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compress and cycle i.e

```
from itertools import compress,cycle


ndf = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randn(2,6), columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'])

ndf[list(compress(ndf.columns,cycle([True]*2 + [False]*2)))]

          A         B         E         F
0  0.833114 -0.616667 -0.908963 -0.486292
1  1.285927 -0.335325  0.562466  1.218459
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write your logic into a function and then iterate through the columns using that function. 
For example, to go by `n2`, use the list slicing syntax `[start:stop:step]` to iterate through the `dataframe.columns`:

```
df = pd. DataFrame() # insert creation code here
cols = [c for c in df.columns[::2] ]
df.loc[:,cols] # result
```

**Edit** this is wrong per the comment.
To skip columns, maybe check the mod of the column position.

```
[val for num, val in enumerate(df.columns) 
if num % 4 in [0,1]]
```

I'm doing this on my phone so sorry if not so nicely formatted

Comment: Dude look the output required and look the output you get after running your code.

Comment: My bad you are correct. But I think there are simpler solutions than needing itertools